# Oracle 11g SQL Sum function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables one called Bank_Account the other Transaction_history the structure is like this:

```
Bank_Account
------------
BankID  
Balance

Transaction_history
------------
TransID  
BankID  
Value
```

I need to add the transaction values to the balance of the bank account, however there could be more than one transaction for each account in the Transaction_History(so for example someone could deposit $1000 and then further down in the table withdraw $500).  How would i code this so that the $500 is taken from the correct account balance?  I've provided an example to try and clarify.

```
Account 1 has a balance of $5000
Account 1 has $1000 deposited
Account 1 has $500 withdrawn
Account 1 current balance is $5500
```

My current code does not take the withdrawl from the new balance but the original.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the following assumptions

- The `VALUE` column in `TRANSACTION_HISTORY` is positive for deposits and negative for withdrawls
- You want to apply all rows from `TRANSACTION_HISTORY` to the current balance of `BANK_ACCOUNT`
- Not every `BankID` that exists in the `BANK_ACCOUNT` table has a transaction in the `TRANSACTION_HISTORY` table

then you'd want a correlated subquery.  Something like

```
UPDATE bank_account acct
   SET balance = balance + (SELECT SUM(th.value)
                              FROM transaction_history th
                             WHERE th.bankID = acct.bankID)
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM transaction_history th
                WHERE th.bankID = acct.bankID )
```

Comment: Hi, thats fantastic that worked and updated my table but my apologies i did not make clear how do i just output (in the script output dialogue box) the correct values - without actually updating the data held in the database (just as though it was a report)